# Create a type with a discriminatory field by combining interfaces?

Tags: typescript

Create a type with a discriminatory field by combining interfaces?

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * Missing changeFn indicates delete
 */
type IChangeRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity extends IBaseEntity> =
    | IUpdateRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity>
    | IDeleteRequestPromiseProxy;

interface IUpdateRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity extends IBaseEntity> {
    id: Id;
    resolve(value: IPersistence<TEntity>): void;
    reject(reason: any): void;
    changeFn(entity: TEntity): IPersistence<TEntity>;
}

interface IDeleteRequestPromiseProxy {
    id: Id;
    resolve(value: void): void;
    reject(reason: any): void;
    changeFn(entity: never): never;
}

let promiseProxy: IChangeRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity> = { id, resolve, reject };
```

Here is the error I get. The gist seems to be that `Property 'changeFn' is missing in type`:

> let promiseProxy: IChangeRequestPromiseProxy Type '{ id:
>   string; resolve: (value?: IPersistence |
>   PromiseLike> | undefined) => void; reject:
>   (reason?: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IChangeRequestPromiseProxy'.   Property 'changeFn' is
>   missing in type '{ id: string; resolve: (value?: IPersistence
>   | PromiseLike> | undefined) => void; reject:
>   (reason?: any) => void; }' but required in type
>   'IUpdateRequestPromiseProxy'.ts(2322) Queue.service.ts(16,
>   5): 'changeFn' is declared here.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`changeFn(entity: never): never;` does not make the property `changeFn` optional. To make it optional you can declare it using `?` and since you don't actually want any value here it should be types as `undefined`

Adding missing types from your question it would look something like:

```
type IChangeRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity extends IBaseEntity> =
    | IUpdateRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity>
    | IDeleteRequestPromiseProxy;

interface IUpdateRequestPromiseProxy<TEntity extends IBaseEntity> {
    id: Id;
    resolve(value: IPersistence<TEntity>): void;
    reject(reason: any): void;
    changeFn(entity: TEntity): IPersistence<TEntity>;
}

interface IDeleteRequestPromiseProxy {
    id: Id;
    resolve(value: void): void;
    reject(reason: any): void;
    changeFn?:undefined;
}

interface IBaseEntity {}
class Entity { }
interface IPersistence<T> { o: T}
type Id = string;
declare const id: string;
declare const resolve: (value: void) =>  void;
declare const reject: (value: any) =>  void;

let promiseProxy: IChangeRequestPromiseProxy<Entity> = { id, resolve, reject };
```